# Dynamically allocating and destroying mutexes?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I have an application that's built on top of Eventlet.

I'm trying to write a decent decorator for synchronizing calls to certain methods across threads.

The decorator currently looks something like this:

```
_semaphores_semaphore = semaphore.Semaphore()
_semaphores = {}

def synchronized(name):
    def wrap(f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # Grab the lock protecting _semaphores.
            with _semaphores_semaphore:
                # If the named semaphore does not yet exist, create it.
                if name not in _semaphores:
                    _semaphores[name] = semaphore.Semaphore()
                sem = _semaphores[name]

            with sem:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works fine, and looks nice and thread safe to me, although this whole thread safety and locking business might be a bit rusty for me.

The problem is that a specific, existing use of semaphores elsewhere in the application, which I'm wanting to convert to using this decorator, creates these semaphores on the fly: Based on user input, it has to create a file. It checks in a dict whether it already has a semaphore for this file, if not, it creates one, and locks it. Once it's done and has released the lock, it checks if it's been locked again (by another process in the mean time), and if not, it deletes the semaphore. This code is written with the assumption of green threads and is safe in that context, but if I want to convert it to use my decorator, and this is what I can't work out.

If I don't care about cleaning up the possibly-never-to-be-used-again semaphores (there could be hundreds of thousands of these), I'm fine. If I do want to clean them up, I'm not sure what to do.

To delete the semaphore, it seems obvious that I need to be holding the _semaphores_semaphore, since I'm manipulating the _semaphores dict, but I have to do something with the specific semaphore, too, but everything I can think of seems to be racy:
 * While inside the "with sem:" block, I could grab the _semaphores_semaphore and sem from _semaphores. However, other threads might be blocked waiting for it (at "with sem:"), and if a new thread comes along wanting to touch the same resource, it will not find the same semaphore in _semaphores, but instead create a new one => fail.
I could improve this slightly by checking the balance of sem to see if another thread is already waiting for me to release it. If so, leave it alone, if not, delete it. This way, the last thread waiting to act on the resource will delete it. However, if a thread has just left the "with _semaphores_semaphore:" block, but hasn't yet made it to "with sem:", I have the same problem as before => fail.

It feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't work out what it is.

Comment: Check `ipcs(1)` output to see if the python semaphores are SYSV or POSIX Semaphores; if so, they will persist even after the application exits, and there is an upper limit on the number of semaphores available. If they are python-internal, perhaps it doesn't matter enough to delete them?

Comment: They look internal, but it still seems silly to keep them around for no good reason. Also, if this were to turn into a natively threaded application, they're bound to be "real" semaphores and thus be a limited resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be able to solve it with a reader-writer lock aka. shared-exclusive lock on the _semaphores dict.
This is untested code, to show the principle. An RWLock implementation can be found in e.g. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413393-multiple-reader-one-writer-mrow-resource-locking/

```
_semaphores_rwlock = RWLock()
_semaphores = {}

def synchronized(name):
    def wrap(f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            lock = _semaphores_rwlock.reader()
            # If the named semaphore does not yet exist, create it.
            if name not in _semaphores:
                lock = _semaphores_rwlock.writer()
                _semaphores[name] = semaphore.Semaphore()

            sem = _semaphores[name]

            with sem:
                retval = f(*args, **kwargs)
            lock.release()
            return retval
```

When you want to clean up you do:

```
wlock = _semaphores_rwlock.writer() #this might take a while; it waits for all readers to release
cleanup(_semaphores)
wlock.release()
```

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. I was just missing the right primitives, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

mchro's answer didn't work for me since it blocks all threads on a single semaphore whenever one thread needs to create a new semaphore.

The answer that I came up with is to keep counters of occupants between the two transactions with `_semaphores` (which are both done behind the same mutex):

```
A: get semaphore
A1: dangerzone
B: with sem: block etc
C: cleanup semaphore
```

The problem is knowing how many people are between `A` and `C`. The counter of the semaphore doesn't tell you that, since someone may be in `A1`. The answer is to keep a counter of entrants along with each semaphore in `_semaphores`, increment it at `A`, decrement it at `C`, and if it's at 0 then you know that there's no-one else in `A`-`C` with the same key and you can safely delete it.